# unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, byte, unpack

When I try to unpack a buffer longer than `4 bytes` I get this error

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes when I unpack the following
```

This is what I'm typing in the shell:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> unpack('<I', b'\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01tzlog_dump\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Does anybody know how to do it with a buffer with a different number of bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You need exactly 23 bytes (not 4)
one example of 23 bytes could be:

```
unpack('>hbI10sbbI', b'\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01tzlog_dump\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03')
```

Check your c struct

Comment: I am trying to dump an img file but it has been impossible.